# Spring MVC controller view

Tags: java, jquery, jsp, spring-mvc

Hey guys, I have a list to be displayed on a view JSP page from the controller side. What do I return from the modelandview function if I want the list to be displayed in the same view page I am calling it from?

Here is the jQuery which i use to call the controller

```
$("#customerList").on("keydown",function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: '/omp/customer',
            type: 'GET'
        });
    });
});
```

Here is the controller code

```
@RequestMapping(method= RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView getlist(Model mod)
{
    System.out.println("I am here");
    CustomerDetails details = new CustomerDetails();
    details.setAl();
    mod.addAttribute("lists",details.getAl());
    return new ModelAndView("dashboard/home");


}
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you want to make an Ajax call to the server and retrieve a list. 
Ajax calls are asynchronous and don't require to load a new page.
My advise is that the controller should return the list in JSON format and some
javascript should parse and display it.

Have a look at @ResponseBody annotation in the Spring MVC documentation.